# Find out which Teredo relay is being used in Windows

Tags: windows, ipv6, teredo

I am using Windows 10. Is it possible to know which Teredo relay is being used by my machine to proxy IPv6 traffic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `netsh` to show Teredo state. Run `cmd` then,

```
netsh interface teredo show state
```

Comment: Of course this can be typed as a single-line command: `netsh interface teredo show state`.